# Dojo require in AMD plugin not firing callback

Tags: asynchronous, dojo

In the following plugin, the load method is correctly called, but the inner callback is never fired:

```
define("App/FooLoader", [], function() {

    return {

        load: function(id, require, callback) {
            require(["App/Foo"], function(foo) {
                callback(foo);
            });

        }
    }
});
```

With the above, I was expecting that when included, like so:

```
// in Bar.js
require(['App/Fooloader!'], function(foo) { // do stuff with foo });
```

That:

1. `App/FooLoader` is loaded, and the `load` method is executed
2. `App/Foo` is loaded, and the inner callback is executed
3. `App/FooLoader` body callback is executed with `foo` the result of loading `App/Foo`.

However, only (1) happens, the callbacks (2) and (3) never happen. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me as below:

```
define("App/Foo", [], function() {
    return 'bar';            
});
define("App/FooLoader", [], function() {
    return {
        load: function(id, require, callback) {
            console.log('inside load', arguments);
            require(["App/Foo"], function(foo) {
                console.log('inside require, foo=', foo);
                callback(foo);
            });
        }
    }
});

require(["App/FooLoader!"], function(fooload) {
  console.log('fooloaded', fooload);
})​
```

I created this JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/fMR3Z/1/

Maybe you have an error in your file structure ?

Comment: Thanks, if there is I can't see it, but you seem to have proved that I've got some other weirdness to deal with.